# If ID exists in javascript array with angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Okay, I'm done searching and trying code blocks that don't work. This is what I got.

I'm building an array when I click on an image.

```
    invoices.addItem = function(id) {
        var itemRef = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/items/'+id);
        itemRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
            invoices.newInvoiceItems.push({
                'id'    : id,
                'name'  : snapshot.val().name,
                'price' : snapshot.val().prices.sale,
                'qty'   : '1'
            });
        }); 
    }
```

I want to check to see if the `ID` passed through when the image is clicked again already exists in the array, if it does increase quantity.

All I'm asking for is a simple way to check if the id exists, if it does return true else return false.

```
if(id exists)
{
  return true;
}
return false;
```

How do I get the id exists working!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!

**UPDATE**

This is everything I have:

```
invoices.addItem = function(id) {
        if(invoices.checkItem(id))
        {
            var index;
            for (index = 0; index < invoices.newInvoiceItems.length; ++index) {
                if(invoices.newInvoiceItems[index].id === id)
                {
                    var qty = invoices.newInvoiceItems[index].qty;
                    invoices.newInvoiceItems[index].qty = qty++;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

            var itemRef = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/items/'+id);
            itemRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
                invoices.newInvoiceItems.push({
                    'id'    : id,
                    'name'  : snapshot.val().name,
                    'price' : snapshot.val().prices.sale,
                    'qty'   : '1'
                });
            });

        }
    }

    invoices.removeItem = function(index) {
        invoices.newInvoiceItems.splice(index, 1);
    }

    invoices.checkItem = function(id) {
        var index;
        for (index = 0; index < invoices.newInvoiceItems.length; ++index) {
            if(invoices.newInvoiceItems[index].id === id)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Let's say I have two items `Item A` and `Item B`. If I click on Item A it adds it to the array. Then click it again and it won't add it but only increases qty one time. Now if I click on Item B without refreshing the page mind you, it adds it over and over and over again each time I click on Item B.

I've console logged the id getting returned and it is always the same one, even though each item has it's own ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to quickly and easily find an item in an array.  If the item is found... then you know it exists.

```
var existingItem = invoices.newInvoiceItems.filter(function(item){
    return item.id === id;
})[0];

if(existingItem ){
    ++existingItem.qty
}else{
    //do your firebase thing...
    var itemRef = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/items/'+id);
    itemRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        invoices.newInvoiceItems.push({
            'id'    : id,
            'name'  : snapshot.val().name,
            'price' : snapshot.val().prices.sale,
            'qty'   : 1
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: SWEET! Now how about increasing qty?

Comment: I made the example more tailored to your specific need.